# Microsoft Teams SSO - Unable to Retrieve Token

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, manifest

I am trying to retrieve an SSO token in my Microsoft Teams task module for a logic am working on and when I use the Microsoft teams SDK I keep getting the error **App resource defined in the manifest and iframe origin do not match**

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

In-app manifest, I have my resources defined as:

```
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "aedd2c2b-545f-4539-9437-8776",
    "resource": "api://subdomain.domain.com/aedd2c2b-545f-4539-9437-8776"
  },
```

In Azure, I have my scope defined in the app created in Azure Active Directory and this is the code below

```
                microsoftTeams.initialize()
                microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({
                    successCallback: (token: string) => {
                        this.setState({ token });
                        this._setAppContextFromMSTContext({ token });
                    },
                    failureCallback: (error) => {
                        this.showAuthenticationError();
                        logger.error(`Error getting token`, error);
                    },
                });
```

But I still can't fetch the token, I keep getting the error below, please let me know what else I am doing wrong

[image: Error getting token]

Comment: Is your tab actually running at https://subdomain.domain.com (or whatever the domain is, does it match the "resource" setting in your app manifest?

Comment: Could you please confirm is above suggestion helped you in any way or are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Yes i am still facing the issue, my resource URLs are the same in app manifest and the tab iframe

Comment: So from the question, what am trying to get is a task module to load jwt token, currently, the task module iframe is using the same subdomain and domain but the path params are different, does that affect anything?

Comment: Could you please refer below document and sample for Tab SSO Authentication
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso?tabs=dotnet

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT, thanks for the recommendation. I actually used that documentation to build my tab and task module applications from the start. I just encounter this jwt token error after using it, I also believe the bug must have been a small tiny detail I haven't observed

Comment: Could you please refer below issue it might help.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/2039

Comment: @TochukwuOzurumba - Could you please confirm is your issue resolved or are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Hi @Nivedipa-MSFT, I am still facing this issue, i even had to leave the project to do some other things, hoping to come back to it when I have a better solution to the problem

Comment: @TochukwuOzurumba - Below sample is in working state. Could you please refer below sample and check all your configuration.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT, thanks for your help so far, I can now retrieve JWT token from SSO. I can't say what did it for me. I had to restart the full taskModule feature and this time it worked. I am grateful for the documentation and links you provided. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Please make sure that the resource specific permissions are granted
  consent to the application.Check if permissions to access teams are added in azure ad portal and granted consent .
- And please recheck the resource parameter is correct by comparing the
  domaina and the client id in  `"resource": "api://{Your tab app domain}/{AAD App client id}"`

References:

1. [understanding-azure-ad-single-sign-on-for-microsoft-teams-apps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/understanding-azure-ad-single-sign-on-for-microsoft-teams-apps/?msclkid=cda0319ebf0411ecbd43aed16348f817)
2. [resource-specific-consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/rsc/resource-specific-consent?msclkid=b4fbbc04bf0211ec9fd17515776a2346)

Comment: Hi @kavyasaraboju-MT, thanks for your answer, my app resources details in manifest match the scope URL "resource": "api://{Your tab app domain}/{AAD App client id}". So there are both the same values and this confuses me the more.


What else can I do or check?